# ScenarioNotFoundException when trying to run jBehave scenario

Tags: java, testing, behavior, jbehave

I've been Google-ing around for a while trying to figure out a fix for this with no real luck.  I'm getting this when trying to run a jBehave test -

```
org.jbehave.scenario.errors.ScenarioNotFoundException: Path '$Path_to_jBehave_Directory' 
could not be found by classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a ...
```

My textual scenario, Steps class, and scenario class are all in the same directory ($Path_to_jBehave_Directory).

This is what I'm using in my maven pom :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be greatly Appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of Path_to_jBehave_Directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven does not automatically copy .story files to test classpath unless you tell it to:

```
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.story</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```